# Python script to create multiple users in a CSV file and generate email addresses

Tags: python

I want to create a csvfile that has multiple users and at the same time create email addresses for this users using their last names. I am using python for this but I can't get it to create the e-mail address in the list. My script is below, what am I missing?

```
import csv

First_Name = ["Test"]
Last_Name = ["User%d" % i for i in range (1,10)]
Email_Address = 'Last_Name' [("@myemail.com")]
Password = ["Password1"]

# open a file for writing.
csv_out = open('mycsv.csv', 'wb')

# create the csv writer object.
mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)

# all rows at once.
rows =zip(Email_Address, Password, First_Name, Last_Name,)
mywriter.writerows(rows)

csv_out.close()
```

Comment: `Email_Address = 'Last_Name' [("@myemail.com")]` This isn't a valid way to create a string and should be throwing an error, it also doesn't look like you posted all of your code for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm basically guessing since you haven't said anything about what errors you're getting, but the most obvious problem I can see is that you're trying to add a string to a list of tuples, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

```
'Last_Name' [("@myemail.com")]
```

should be:

```
'Last_Name' + "@myemail.com"
```

Now, as far as what you're actually trying to do, which is extremely unclear, I think you want to use a series of list comprehensions. For example:

```
users = [i for i in range(0, 10)]
first_names = ["test"+str(user) for user in users]
last_names = ["User%d" %user for user in users]
email_addresses = [last_name + "@myemail.com" for last_name in last_names]
passwords = ["Password1" for user in users]

with open('mycsv.csv', 'wb') as csv_out:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_out)
    writer.writerows(zip(email_addresses, passwords, first_names, last_names))
```

output:

```
User0@myemail.com,Password1,test0,User0
User1@myemail.com,Password1,test1,User1
User2@myemail.com,Password1,test2,User2
User3@myemail.com,Password1,test3,User3
User4@myemail.com,Password1,test4,User4
User5@myemail.com,Password1,test5,User5
User6@myemail.com,Password1,test6,User6
User7@myemail.com,Password1,test7,User7
User8@myemail.com,Password1,test8,User8
User9@myemail.com,Password1,test9,User9
```

Comment: It does if he's trying to add that string to every element of the list.  Still illegal syntax, no matter what the desire.

Comment: @ScottHunter yea, I couldn't really tell at all what OP was asking for. This is my best guess though and I hope it's not that far off?

Comment: What I am trying to achive was write a csv file that will contain multiple users with email and a fixed password "Password1". My issue was with the email and printing all the users in 10 rows. I see that zip is stopping my iteration. what method do i use to write the row with 10 users

Comment: @user2547206 that code above should be what you're looking for then.

Comment: it didnt write the mycsv.csv file

Comment: I am just getting one row since I have the zip function in the above script

Comment: @user2547206 by the script above I meant my script, not yours. Runs exactly as is (assuming you've imported csv somewhere)

Comment: I am using your script but its only giving me one row for first user its not showing the other 9

Comment: @user2547206 copy and paste my script exactly as is. I just ran it and it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
Email_Address = 'Last_Name' [("@myemail.com")]
```

into

```
Email_Address = [x + "@myemail.com" for x in Last_Name]
```

to create a list of all email addresses based on all last names. This assumes you intended for all of your variables to be lists.

Even though this will create ten emails (one for each last name) your file will only have one row written to it. This is because `zip` will stop iteration at the length of the shortest list you pass it. Currently `First_Name` and `Password` each contain only one item.

Comment: What I am trying to achive was write a csv file that will contain multiple users with email and a fixed password "Password1". My issue was with the email and printing all the users in 10 rows. I see that zip is stopping my iteration. what method do i use to write the row with 10 users

Answer (score 0):

Your zip() will only produce a list w/ 1 item b/c First_Name and Password explicitly each contain only 1 item.

How about this, avoiding the zip entirely:

```
with open('mycsv.csv', 'wb') as csv_out:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_out)
    for i in xrange(1,9):
        writer.writerow( ["User%d@myemail.com"%i, "Password%d"%i, "test%d"%i, "User%d"%i] )
```

Comment: So how do I get it to print all the users in a row ?